# Integrate Dialogflow with Actions on Google with intents using Fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

When I try to interact with Actions on Google it does not respond when the intent has Fulfillment active.

I receive this error in the logs of Google Cloud Platform:

```
MalformedResponse: Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response
```

My webhook is responding with a follow-up event input. Here is the response from my API:

```
{
  "followupEventInput": {
    "name": "campo-harmonico-found",
    "languageCode": "pt-BR",
    "parameters": {
      "campo-harmonico": "campo harmônico de dó maior ou campo harmônico de ré maior"
    }
  }
}
```

The Intent that should call my webhook:

[image: Intent that should call a webhook]

The Intent that should be called after webhook respond:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the Intent or Intents you think should be triggered by your response, any code that you're using, etc? See [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Comment: @Prisoner, yes, of course, I updated it.

Comment: Have you enabled to use the default response for Google Assistant from the Google Assistant tab? If not, enable it and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but two things jump out at me.

1. Your `campo-harmonico-found` Intent has both Training Phrases and an Event set. You should only have one or the other. I would expect that the Event would take priority, but this could be confusing Dialogflow.
2. It isn't clear that you need to use `followupEventInput` at all. If your purpose is to just reply with this message - you can just reply with the message from the `acorde` Intent Handler. Most of the time we don't need to use Followup Events, we should just return the reply that we want from the Intent handler itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention.
I've used a training phrase because without it Dialogflow shows the following error when integrating with Google Assistant: "Request contains an invalid argument.
Query pattern is missing for custom intent 'field-harmonic-found' ".
I want to use a `followupEventInput` to be able to define the answers in Dialogflow, this way it is easier to have a lot of different answers defined by a copywriter for example.

Comment: @Prisoner May you help to resolve the issue I am facing. This is the link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67548238/not-able-to-add-the-intent-from-dialogflow-to-google-assistant