# Not able to add the intent from Dialogflow to Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant

Ok I am using the Dialogflow Essentials and there are several intents are already defined which were  integrated with google assistant and these intents works fine,But now I made new intent in Dialogflow and it works fine in `try now` option but when I tried to integrate it with google assistant (`Dialogflow ------> Integrations ------> Google Assistant ------->continue with integration`  ), I can not see the new intent in the List (pop up with previous intents and their check boxes ). May some one help me to know why the new intent is not visible in the list ?

The following screen shot image shows the corresponding error message

[image]

The error message reads:

> The maximum number of intents is 10.

Answer (score 0):

You are limited to 10 "deep link" Intents that would be used as part of the Action invocation. These enable you to say things like "Ask Super Action to Turn the lights on". Instead of just "Talk to Super Action" and then, while it is running, asking it to turn the lights on.

You are allowed many more Intents themselves - but just 10 that can be used as part of the invocation phrase.

If this is actually for controlling Smart Home devices, you may wish to look into the [Smart Home](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) integration for the Google Assistant instead. This lets people control your devices directly through commands to the Assistant ("Hey Google, Turn on the bedroom lights") instead of having to go through an Action you've written ("Hey Google, Ask Super Home to turn on the bedroom lights"). This method does not involve Dialogflow at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are already using(smart home ) what you suggested in your second opinion. Now for the Dialogflow to Google Assistant the integration pop up we already have 21(implicit) intents which works fine for utterance `Ask Super Action to Turn the lights on`. Now when we go any new intents it does not work and show the error as said above. Even we tried to remove the previous intents (which is not getting remove from the action console) and add  them again but it does not get added.